# Rails: Loading animation while rendering partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I know similar questions have been asked here before, but my situation's a little different so I don't think this is a duplicate.

I'm following along with Bate's tutorial on infinite scroll. I have a loading animation working when fetching more posts. My problem is that I would like a loading animation to display when fetching the initial partial.

How would I display a loading animation when fetching a partial in Rails? Looking for a Rails 3.x.x solution..

Thank you in advance

---

Basically what I have now is

```
<% if @posts %>
    <%= render @posts %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How are you fetching the partial?

Comment: @josnidhin Using the code above (render posts)